# Swift - How to popViewControllerAnimated two views back

Tags: swift, swift2

I have my Storyboard with some `UIViewControllers` and my main `UINavigationController`.

Then I have a UIViewController where on `tableView` `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I pop the `UIViewController`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!){

        let provider = self.results[indexPath.row]

        self.delegate?.didProviderSelected(provider)
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

This works fine because then I return to the previous view but what I need to return two views back.

> How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

You can use 
`popToViewController(_:animated:)` to pop previous two views:

```
if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
    if viewControllers.count > 3 {
        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 3], animated: true)
    } else {
                // fail
    }
}
```

Comment: Since both the question and your answer are in Swift, you might consider formatting the inline method signature as `popToViewController(_:animated:)` instead of `-popToViewController:animated:`

Answer (score 3):

`UINavigationController` keep the pushed controllers in stack. So you can just specify which index of viewController to show.

```
let controller = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[1] // it is at index 1. index start from 0, 1 .. N    
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(controller!, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove not showed view controller "behind scene" before poping animated:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    let provider = self.results[indexPath.row]

    self.delegate?.didProviderSelected(provider)
    if let count = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count where count > 2 {
        self.navigationController?.viewControllers.removeAtIndex(count - 2)
    }
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need is an Unwind Segue, check [this post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/)

You'll need to create a method with the following signature (the blog post in that link is on Objective C)

```
@IBAction func segueUnwinder(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    return
}
```

The unwind segue should let you go back as far as you need in your navigation stack.

Good Luck!