# Swift & Navigation : How do I pop until a certain ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, navigation, storyboard

In order to pop to Root ViewController, I can just use the following code.

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

But what if I want to pop until a certain View Controller in the Navigation stack, how can I do that? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Use `viewControllers` property of the navigation controller to find which one you want to pop to, and then call `popToViewController(_:animated:)` to pop to it.

Comment: Could you show me a sample code?

Comment: How do you know which view controller you want to pop to? What's the logic behind it?

Comment: Say I did this. One -> Two -> Three -> Four -> Five. And I want to pop from Five until Two. How do I do that?

Comment: `guard let navigationController = navigationController else { return }; let targetVC = navigationController.viewControllers[1]; navigationController.popToViewController:(targetVC, animated: true)` ? It's pretty straightforward, I don't see the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339737/swift-how-to-popviewcontrolleranimated-two-views-back/38341017 or if it's by class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343546/how-to-pop-view-controller-to-one-of-the-previous-view-controllers-in-swift

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift - How to popViewControllerAnimated two views back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339737/swift-how-to-popviewcontrolleranimated-two-views-back)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The navigation controller holds a group of view controller and you can pop to any sub-controller you want. For example your flow seem like:

> `HomeViewController` -> `ContactViewController` -> `ContactDetailsViewController` -> `ChatViewController`

Then from `ChatViewController` you want to push back to `ContactViewController`:

```swift
class ChatViewController: UIViewController {
    ....
    func popToContact() {
        if let contactVC = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.filter { $0 is ContactViewController }.first {
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(contactVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```